# Flutter: Merge objects of same type and combine defined properties (like javascript?)

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Flutter and Dart, lets say I have this class:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  @JsonKey(nullable: true, required: false)
  final String name;

  @JsonKey(nullable: true, required: false)
  final int age;

  User({
    this.name,
    this.age,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AddressFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddressToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'User ${toJson().toString()}';
  }
}
```

In my code I'm trying to create a new instance of this class to be sent to `/update-user` endpoint on the server. My goal is to send an object that contains just the properties I would like the server to update. let's say only update `age`.

Using

```
    final dto = new UpdateUserRequest(
      age: 34
    );
```

results in this json representation: `{name: null, age: 34}`, which will override the already existing name on the server.

I also tried 'json merging' 2 objects, the one I already have with the `name`, and the new dto that updates `age`:

```
    final combined = UpdateUserRequest.fromJson({
      ...(dtoWithAge.toJson()),
      ...(existingUserWithName.toJson()),
    });
```

but no matter how I play around with these, they end up overriding each other.

So, is there anyway to get a json/DTO instance of the class, that only contains the properties and values I want the server to update? (trying to achieve something very similar to javascript)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a pre-implemented solution for that. Assuming I understood what you're trying to accomplish, how about adding a `copyWith` method to `User`?

```
User copyWith({
  String name,
  int age,
}) => User(
    name: name ?? this.name,
    age: age ?? this.age,
  );
```

You'd use it like this:

```
final existingUser = User(name: 'John');
final updatedUser = existingUser.copyWith(age: 25);
sendUpdateRequestWith(updatedUser);
```

For you convenience, there's a plugin to generate it.

- vscode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator
- IDEA/Android Studio: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12429-dart-data-class

Comment: Thanks! The suggested plugin does not directly solves my problem, but allows me to at least simple configure copyWith methods for classes, so I can merge any existing data with new data values I want to write, and send a 'complete' object to the server for updating, without too much manual labor.